# Problems with Jquery Scrollpane, Ajaxed dynamic loaded Content ann Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jscrollpane, dynamic-content

i have the problem that my wp site works great, but the jscrollpane isn't loaded on the dynamic displayed content!

You can see it here : [www.ra-sittig.de](http://www.ra-sittig.de/)

Her you can see the problem! If you click the url like this format:

[www.ra-sittig.de/zeugenbeistandschaft](http://www.ra-sittig.de/zeugenbeistandschaft)

Then you can see the scrollpane works but so on the ajaxed laoded content doesn't work!

Ich you click the normal way of the genereted links like this (you can check it on homepage! ) 
http://www.ra-sittig.de/#url=http%3A//www.ra-sittig.de/zeugenbeistandschaft

Then the ajaxed content loads but not the scroll-pane! What can i do to figure this out, cause need thes get work asap cause it is a client work, can you help me reletad to this issue!

Does anybody have an suggestion what can i do to get this work!

If you need code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {         //since your site is calling jQuery.noConflict()
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
  });
</script>
```

This is the one on header.php

And this ist the .js code of the ajaxed loaded content called ajax-for-all.js

```
/**
 * TODO
 *
 * Back/forward history
 * Forms ?
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    /**
     * Dispatcher class.
     *
     * @since 0.3
     */
    function AjaxForAllDispatcher() {
        this.completed  = 0;
        this.request    = new AjaxForAllRequest;
        this.tmp        = '';
        this.fire       = function(href) {
            if ( this.completed == 0 ) {
                this.step(false);
                div.hide();
                this.content = this.request.get(href);
            }
        }
        this.step       = function(content) {
            this.completed = this.completed + 1;
            if ( content != false ) {
                this.tmp = content;
            }
            if ( this.completed == 3 ) {
                div.reveal(this.tmp);
                this.completed = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Div class. The div that we will replace.
     *
     * @since 0.3
     */
    function AjaxForAllDiv() {
        this.width      = 0;
        this.height     = 0;
        this.id         = afa_id;
        this.preserve   = afa_preserve_size;
        this.transition = ajax_for_all_transition;
        this.transtime  = ajax_for_all_transtime;
        this.scrolltop  = ajax_for_all_scrolltop;
        this.scrolltime = ajax_for_all_scrolltime;
        this.hide       = function() {
            if ( this.preserve == true ) {
                this.height = $('#content').css( 'height' );
                this.width = $('#content').css( 'width' );
                $('#' + this.id ).wrapInner( '<div id="afasize" />' );
                $('#afasize').wrapInner( '<div id="afacontent" />' );
                $('#afasize').css( 'height', this.height );
                $('#afasize').css( 'width', this.width );
            }
            else {
                $('#' + this.id ).wrapInner( '<div id="afacontent" />' );
            }
            $('#' + this.id ).prepend( '<div id="afaspinner"> </div>' );
            $('#afaspinner').fadeIn();
            // scroll to top
            if (this.scrolltop) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, this.scrolltime);
            }
            // transition
            switch (this.transition) {
                case 'none':
                    dispatcher.step(false);
                break;
                case 'fade':
                    $('#afacontent').fadeOut(
                        this.transtime,
                        function() {
                            dispatcher.step(false);
                        }
                    );
                break;
                default:
                case 'slide':
                    $('#afacontent').slideUp(
                        this.transtime,
                        function() {
                            dispatcher.step(false);
                        }
                    );
                break;
            }
        }
        this.reveal = function(tmp) {
            if ( typeof AjaxForAllCallback == 'function' ) {
                AjaxForAllCallback(tmp); // callback that gets all the data
            }
            // transition
            switch (this.transition) {
                case 'none':
                    $('#' + this.id ).html(tmp.content);
                break;
                case 'fade':
                    $('#' + this.id ).html(tmp.content);
                    $('#' + this.id ).fadeIn(this.transtime);
                break;
                default:
                case 'slide':
                    $('#' + this.id ).hide();
                    $('#' + this.id ).html(tmp.content);
                    $('#' + this.id ).slideDown(this.transtime);
                break;
            }
            // The position seems to be accurate even when the slideDown isn't
            // finished yet:
            if ( tmp.jump ) {
                anchor  = $('a[name|=' + tmp.jumpto + ']');
                offset  = anchor.offset();
                ytop    = offset.top;
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: ytop
                }, this.scrolltime);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Request class. Gets the content we will inject.
     *
     * @since 0.3
     */
    function AjaxForAllRequest() {
        this.ajaxurl    = ajaxurl;
        this.user       = ajax_for_all_curl_user;
        this.nonce      = ajax_for_all_curl_nonce;
        this.get        = function(href) {
            $.getJSON(
                this.ajaxurl, {
                    action: 'ajax_for_all',
                    href: href,
                    user: this.user,
                    nonce: this.nonce
                }, function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        dispatcher.step(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        // just follow the link then
                        window.location = href;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate the unique objects
     */
    dispatcher = new AjaxForAllDispatcher();
    div = new AjaxForAllDiv();

    /**
     * Event binding
     */
    $('a').live( 'click',
        function() {
            if ( $(this).attr('target') ) {
                return true;
            }
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $.bbq.pushState({ url: href });
            if ( href.indexOf('#') == 0 ) {
                return true;
            }
            dispatcher.fire(href);
            return false;
        }
    );

    // Bind a callback that executes when document.location.hash changes.
    $(window).bind( "hashchange", function(e) {
        var hash = e.getState( 'url' );
        if ( hash !== undefined ) {
            dispatcher.fire(hash);
        }
        else if ( window.location != afa_root ) {
            dispatcher.fire(afa_root);
        }
    });

    if ( afa_nodeeplink != 'on' ) {
        $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
    }

});
```

PLs help me to figure this problem out! 
Thank you for your advices!

kind regards

cominaction

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize the scroll pane again after the ajax content is loaded (now it is only done when the page is ready). Just add it in the

```
if(data.success){ 
    dispatcher.step(data);
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
}
```

Comment: Sry but can you discribe it !? Have problems to get this work

Comment: Nothing happens! www.ra-sittig.de :) what do you have change cant find changes

Comment: i get crazy with this scrollpane issue

Comment: Hi Phil, I had another look at your code and I think first need to clean up a bit... you are including jQuery 4 times and with different versions (1.2.2, 2x1.4.2, 1.4.4)...

Comment: is it ok only to combine the latest jquery or must including more than one to get this work ! Thinking the latest jquery with all extension must be enough or!?

Comment: so now i have only only one jquery 1.42. and one jquerypack 1.2.2

Comment: but when i try to get the 1.4.2 pack the hovertips on the top nav doens't work then

Comment: so i have now integrate 1.5 is it so ok !?

Comment: hey Bjorn, i dont know if i disable the other jquery nothing works in site ! What can i do, cause must present the site in Tuesday and still have no luck to this work

Comment: Sorry had missed your comments. You need to check which jquery version the different plugins work with (probably easiest to only add them one at a time). In the end you must select one version to work with even if it means that you need to abandon one of the plugins.